# SWRevealViewController sidebar menu button does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, swrevealviewcontroller

SWRevealViewController menu button only works during the first load out of the the view. However, it would not slide out anymore whenever the search button is clicked. During debugging I tried changing the functionality of the search button into a reload function just to test. Then I found out that I still get the same bug in the menu button. It never slides out.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code for the search button and menu button.

```
//Original Code
_searchButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
_searchButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[_searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(searchHospital) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

//Modified Code
_searchButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
_searchButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[_searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadThisView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];       

//definition for reloadThisView
- (void)reloadThisView {
    [self viewDidLoad];
}

//code for Menu bar button item; in viewDidLoad
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-tab.png"];
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

UIBarButtonItem *rightRevealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:revealController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightRevealButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"new-logo"]]];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

Now the question is; what are the possible reasons that a menu button running on SWRevealViewController class, would malfunction?

Comment: It never works or it works only for the first time??

Comment: It works only for the first time.